# C# Calling Base Class Constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

```
public CArm(Vector3 at, string name) : base(name)
{

}
```

Is there any other way to call base parent constructor within the brackets instead of doing `: base(name)`?

I'm not sure if this was another language but I recall something like `super();` inside of the constructor to call the base class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, you cannot call base constructors inside constructor bodies in C#. You're probably thinking of Java's syntax.

You can emulate the desired behavior by calling a method instead. Just make sure to be very careful about calling virtual methods!

Comment: Or VB.NET's syntax, but the call to the base constructor still must be the *first line* in the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

no, you can't . super keyword is used in java for calling superclass methods and objects.